# How to convert 3gp files on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

I'm working on iOS, but in fact 3gp+AMR files can't be played using MPMediaPlyer, may be I need to convert it to 3gp+AAC, how can I do that?
here is the code, it works well on MP4 files.

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"123" ofType:@"3gp"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    _movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    _movieplayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    _movieplayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    _movieplayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [self.view addSubview:_movieplayer.view];`

**As  descripted on Apples Docs for MPMediaPlayer:**

Supported Formats

This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, **this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz**, stereo audio.`

Comment: OK. I've post the code for playing media files.

Comment: the code you posted just plays media. where's the code you've tried to convert with?

Comment: @JoeHabadas That's what I'm thinking about. I've not find any solutions for 3gp+AMR files on iOS.